# Grouping results of query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a subform in an Access form that is the result of the following query

```
SELECT c.clientName, o.year, o.id, o.bill_id, o.comment
FROM clients c, orders o
WHERE o.c_id=c.id
```

The query works fine, but the view is not as good as I wanted it to be. The question is, is it possible to output the data in the following way?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|           |        year1         |         year2         |
------------------------------------------------------------
|Name       |o.id|o.bill_id|comment||o.id|o.bill_id|comment|
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So to say the orders are grouped via the year. I just need a direction, in which I can research in.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Yes, use a crosstab query. There is even a wizard to create it.

Comment: Why not group by `Name` and `Year` in an aggregate `GROUP BY` query? This looks harder to read. And do note: such a crosstab query will not be updateable via subform.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what Year1 and Year2 are, or can you put them in a table?  Then you can use iif statements to get the 6 columns you want:

```
SELECT c.clientName, max(iif(o.year="2017",o.id)) as "2017 ID", max(iif(o.year="2017", o.bill_id)) as "2017 Biid ID) ....
FROM clients c, orders o
WHERE o.c_id=c.id
Group by c.clientname
```

You cannot use a crosstab query to get more than one set of columns, of course.